# How to run background service at eveytime i click the Controller (GetAllUsers)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

Actually iam trying to run my controller and backgroundService at the same time. But my controller want to execute the background service at each time when iam getting the **GetAllUsers**. My Controller want to give results without waiting for the end of the await in BackgroundService.( I want to run my background service in parallel).

This is my sample code of UserController

```
private readonly ILogger<UsersController> _logger;

public UserController(ILogger<UserController> logger)
{
  _logger = logger;
}

[HttpGet]

public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllUsers(CancellationToken stoppingToken)

{
     _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService Started at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);

     await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), stoppingToken);  

     _logger.LogInformation("Executing user Donnes");

     List<UserDto> user = listUsers;

     await StopAsync(stoppingToken);

     return new OkObjectResult(user);

}

private async Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   _logger.LogInformation("MyBackgroundService stopped at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
   await StopAsync(stoppingToken);
}
```

Comment: What is your question? How does this piece of code not behave as you expect? I also do not see anything close to a "background service" here?

Comment: want to restart the bacgroundservice at every time i click the GetAllUser. And the list have to post without waiting for the Background Service time. The service have to be run in parellel.

Comment: Are you OK with losing any background work whenever the app is restarted (e.g., during a rolling upgrade)?

Comment: I think Yes, I wil set a stopAsync To 10 sec

Comment: In that case, you can use a [queued background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#queued-background-tasks). Note that there is only one background *service* that just processes queue items until the app is shut down.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think mix up backgroudservice and controller is a good idea. You could try following sample which start and stop a backgroundservice from a controller.
ServiceProviderExtensions.cs

```
    public static class ServiceProviderExtensions
    {
        public static TWorkerType GetHostedService<TWorkerType>
            (this IServiceProvider serviceProvider) =>
            serviceProvider
                .GetServices<IHostedService>()
                .OfType<TWorkerType>()
                .FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

myservice.cs

```
    public class myservice : BackgroundService
    {

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("myservice running");
                await Task.Delay(1000, stoppingToken);
            }
            await Task.CompletedTask;

        }

    }
```

program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<HostOptions>(hostOptions =>
{
    hostOptions.BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior = BackgroundServiceExceptionBehavior.Ignore;
});
builder.Services.AddHostedService<myservice>();
```

Controller

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("stop")]
        public async Task testStop()
        {
            var worker = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetHostedService<myservice>();

            await worker.StopAsync(new CancellationToken());
        }
        [HttpGet("start")]
        public async Task testStart()
        {
            var worker = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetHostedService<myservice>();

            await worker.StartAsync(new CancellationToken());
        }
    }
```

Test
[image]